# Excel =RAND() returns #name

Tags: excel, random, xls

I'm very new to excel and I've been trying to generate a random number, but excel keeps telling me #NAME (#NOMBRE in my case cause I have the Spanish version). What am I doing wrong? I'm using .xls, not .xslx, but that shouldn't matter, no?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is Spanish for RAND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
ALEATORIO
```

in place of `RAND`

This may be of help:

[Translations](http://www.excelfunctions.eu/)